# How to prevent free distribution of a commercial Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, frameworks

I'm not sure if this is more appropriate under a different SE site (Super User?).

I want to build and sell a complex macro driven driven spreadsheet to a certain vertical. I am mainly concerned about free/unauthorised distribution between customers within that vertical.

I can see that there is a few obscure products on the market that might be able to do what I want, but the few reviews that i've been able to find haven't been favourable.

One vendor however lists that free distribution can circumvented by either:

- Using a key generator to create license codes
- Using the online activation feature
- Or by simply using an encrypted password

Is anyone aware of any guidelines/frameworks (any language) for me to build my own solution to achieve this, namely requiring licence codes or online activation?

If this is generally a difficult endeavour, is there a commercial product that anyone recommend?

I'm also thinking the complexities involved in achieving this might push me to building a small SaaS application instead. Am I better off just going that route?

Comment: Before this gets migrated, though... `Scriptlet.TypeLib` can be used to create `GUID`s which you can then use as a license code of sorts when you're distributing them (of course, tracking said `GUID`s is a given.). Hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have created an Excel sheet that I could remotely remove access to if a monthly subscription payment failed. Here is how to accomplish this:

1. Create and HTML table and upload it to your website
2. Within your Excel doc go to the data tab and select get from web - import your table into a sheet called "Verify" - make sure your table has 3 columns. Serial Number is in the first column, description of user in 2nd, and your error message in the top of col 3. The error message stored here is what every user that isn't registered will see. The first serial number should appear in cell A2 of the sheet Verify.

Within your Visual Basic editor paste this code into a Module - This code will return an 8 digit serial number based on a PC's Hard Drive serial number:

```
Function HDSerialNumber() As String
     Dim fsObj   As Object
    Dim drv     As Object
    Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set drv = fsObj.Drives("C")

    HDSerialNumber = Left(Hex(drv.SerialNumber), 4) _
         & "-" & Right(Hex(drv.SerialNumber), 4)
End Function
```

Also in another module I make sure the Internet is connected. If no Internet then the sheet closes. If you don't do this then if someone disconnects from the Internet your serials won't be loaded.

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedStateEx Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef lpdwFlags As Long, ByVal lpszConnectionName As String, ByVal dwNameLen As Integer, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedStateEx Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef lpdwFlags As Long, ByVal lpszConnectionName As String, ByVal dwNameLen As Integer, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
#End If


Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean

Dim strConnType As String, lngReturnStatus As Long, MyScript As String

    If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Macintosh*" Then
        MyScript = "repeat with i from 1 to 2" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "try" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "do shell script ""ping -o -t 2 www.apple.com""" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "set mystatus to 1" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "exit repeat" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "on error" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "If i = 2 Then set mystatus to 0" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "end try" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "end repeat" & vbNewLine
        MyScript = MyScript & "return mystatus"
        If MacScript(MyScript) Then IsInternetConnected = True
    Else
        lngReturnStatus = InternetGetConnectedStateEx(lngReturnStatus, strConnType, 254, 0)
        If lngReturnStatus = 1 Then IsInternetConnected = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then inside the Workbook_Open area paste this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If IsInternetConnected Then

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sBuf As String
Dim trialstartdate As String
Dim z As String

Dim fsoFSO
Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


'UNCOMMENT below to SHOW the serials sheet when the workbook is opened
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Verify").Visible = xlSheetVisible

'UNCOMMENT below to hide the serials sheet when the workbook is opened
'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Verify").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

Refresh_Serials
    z = 2
    'loop here for valid hard drive serial number
    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Verify").Cells(z, 1).Value)
        If Worksheets("Verify").Cells(z, 1).Value = HDSerialNumber Then
        'verified and let pass

        GoTo SerialVerified
        End If
        z = z + 1

        Loop

Dim custommessage As String

custommessage = Worksheets("Verify").Cells(2, 3)

MsgBox custommessage + " Your serial number is: " + HDSerialNumber

            Dim wsh1, MyKey1
            Set wsh1 = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
            MyKey1 = "%{TAB}"
            wsh1.SendKeys MyKey1


             MsgBox "The Commission Tracker will not open without a valid serial number. It will now close. uncomment this in workbook->open to close the workbook if the serial isn't found"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'uncomment this to close the workbook if the serial isn't found
             'ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

SerialVerified:

' does the end user agree to not use this tool for mailicous purposes?

MsgAgree = MsgBox("Your PC's serial number is " & HDSerialNumber & ". By clicking 'Yes' you agree to use our software as described in our end user agreement. - the URL to your terms here", vbYesNo, "Final Agreement")

    If MsgAgree = vbNo Then
    'close program
    MsgBox "This program will now close since you do not agree to our end user agreement"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Else
    'continue to open the program

    End If

Else
   MsgBox "No Network Connection Detected - You must have an internet connection to run the commission tracker."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If


End Sub
```

That should do it....

Answer (score 2):

Create your own special unique license keys in a macro that will unlikely be generated in a key generator.  Add your own prefix, for example.  You could store if a user is using it in an online database.  Downfall to this solution is that the users would have to be connected to the outside internet.

Then lock down that module with the keys by the following:

To protect your code, open the Excel Workbook and go to Tools>Macro>Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11). Now, from within the VBE go to Tools>VBAProject Properties and then click the Protection page tab and then check "Lock project from viewing" and then enter your password and again to confirm it. After doing this you must save, close & reopen the Workbook for the protection to take effect.