# How to Prevent Free Distribution of Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I reviewed the answer to the question at the link below.  This seems to match my need, but I am not able to get it to work for me.   What am I doing wrong so this will work.  This code can be a great tool for me to limit the free distribution of my spreadsheet which I have commercialized.

Thank you for the help.

[How to prevent free distribution of a commercial Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649736/how-to-prevent-free-distribution-of-a-commercial-excel-spreadsheet?answertab=active#tab-top)

When I put the code into the modules and save the file, when the file is opened I am receiving the following error.

```
Compile Error:
Sub or Function not defined
```

It then highlights the reference to "Refresh_Serials".

I am running this currently on Excel 2007.  Do I need to try it on a newer version of Excel maybe?

I have used the same code as included in the link below.

I would expect it to do as expected per the original post, although I am not 100% sure exactly what the outcome should be.  Maybe part of my gap at this point is that I haven't yet established the HTML table.  Could I use a "Google Sheet" instead with a table in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this Workbook to be compatible for Specific Users only. Then one way to achieve it is to add a `WorkBook_Open` event. Like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


    If Not Application.UserName = "Mohit Bansal" Then

        MsgBox "Not the Correct User"

        ThisWorkbook.Close False

    End If


End Sub
```

Change the Name as Per the User, and lock the VBA Project. You can even make a list of names to check from if multiple users are going to use it.

This will make sure that only one user is able to use the Workbook.

There are obviously other complicated & efficient ways to achieve this, but I prefer this one for Simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linked to code source (what the actions are that follow that line) and the coding style of the author I think that `Refresh_Serials` is in fact a label. It should be `Refresh_Serials:`. The lack of the ":" means the compiler is expecting a sub/function of that name. As there are no `GoTo` statements these labels, there is another proper label further on,`SerialVerified:`,  are unnecessary and confusing. They could simply be comments. Better still, go more [Single Responsibility Principle](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/oop-vba-pt-1-debunking-stuff/) and have functions/subs with names akin to those labels and shift the relevant re-factored code into them.

Comment: Did this answer your question?